# How to do I find all the users who have given me a specific Facebook extended permission?

Tags: facebook

I have requested the email extended permission for my Facebook application.  I want to be able to find out all the users who have given me this permission.  Is there a way to query this information through Facebook?

I know I can use users.hasAppPermission with the old rest api to find this for users who are logged in.  I need the data for users who are not currently logged into the site or may never come back to the site.

Comment: Do you have a list of user ids?

Comment: Yes, I have all the users' facebook ids

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible with Facebook currently without offline access to the users data.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like API allows you to check only current user's permissions.

To check for email permissions you can retrieve `email` field from a `user` table through FQL for all your users. If it is not empty - user granted you email permission. As a bonus you collect all emails (that's probably what your goal is at the end anyway). To speed things up you can run queries in batches:

```
select uid, email from user where uid in (1,2,..,1000)
                                      ...(1001,..,2000)
                                      ...
```

(this assumes that you have `offline_access` permission)

Comment: I don't have offline access and retrieving only the active users permissions does not help me in this situation.  It seems like you should be able to find out what percent of users have provided an extended permission via Facebook.  Maybe Facebook has left this functionality out.

Comment: @Nicolo77 if you don't have even offline access then you pretty much can't do anything with the user.

Comment: I guess maybe I'm not approaching this correctly.  I really don't care about the individual user.  I just need to know what percent of my users have given me the email extended permission.  It sounds like there may be no solution to this.